# how to add a variable into a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanna turn this

```
document.getElementById('group_'+group).value = attribute;
```

into jquery format so that it looks cleaner.
i tried this and it doesnt work

```
$("#group_" +group).val() = attribute;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you're assigning the *result* of the `.val()` invocation equal to the `attribute` variable, this is completely wrong.

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) takes an argument for the value you wish to assign, so this code would work:

```
$("#group_" +group).val(attribute);
```

Your `id` selector is perfectly fine.